# How do I use LIKE with % in a Select Query in Go for MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, go

I want to get a list of records from a SQL database using LIKE with % before and after the search term. I'm using the github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb package. My query is as follows currently:

`row, err := DB.Query("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name LIKE %@p1%", nameToSearch)`

This throws the error: `Incorrect syntax near '@p1'.`

I've tried other variations of the query including the following:

- `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name LIKE '%%' @p1 '%%'`
- `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name LIKE '%%' || @p1 || '%%'`
  These fail as well.

Is the driver I'm using not able to support Like's with wildcards?

Comment: The syntax for MSSQL should be `like '%' + @p1 + '%'`.  Try that with your driver and see if it works.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is for SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @APH, that worked! I had thought I tried that variation as well, but guess not.

Comment: @JHizzal . . . Pass the value in as a parameter and add the wildcards in the app.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do you mean exactly? How would that be different than APH's comment?

Comment: @JHizzal . . . Totally different.  Create the pattern in the application and pass it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness/in case comments are lost - in T-SQL/MS SQL, the syntax to use a variable as a wildcard is:

```
DECLARE @p1 VARCHAR(10) = 'test' --declare and set variable

print '%' + @p1 + '%' --for example to see concatenation (not necessary for code below)
print '%@p1%' --compared to incorrect syntax treating @p1 as a string rather than a variable

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column LIKE '%' + @p1 + '%' --correct syntax for wildcard criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @APH, but the correct syntax within the GO code is:

`row, err := DB.Query("SELECT * FROM wsd.CUSMASFL WHERE CMNAME LIKE '%' + @p1 + '%'", nameToSearch)`

Comment: Glad it worked!  Added a little more detail below for future askers' reference.